# Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

Tags: swift

I'm getting a 'Type of expression is ambiguous with a type annotation' error. I'm using the latest beta version of Xcode and Swift. I can't seem to figure it out. I tried different things but can't get it to work.
The problem is on the syntax of this line

```swift
if let build = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
   return build
}
```

Here's my full code:

```swift
extension Bundle {
    class var applicationVersionNumber: String {
        if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] {
            var applicationBuildNumber: String {
                if let build = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
                    return build
                }
                return "Build Number Not Available"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SLInfoView: View {
    let versionNumber = Bundle.applicationVersionNumber
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section() {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Version")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(versionNumber)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("General infos")
                } footer: {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
                .navigationTitle("Info")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SLInfoView()
}
```

I want to get the version number from my application to show my version and build number in a SwiftUI View. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: It is a typo, comment out sections until you find it

Comment: ok thanks lorem ipsum I'll try that

Comment: Maybe the else for "if let version", you should learn about "guard"

Comment: Any reason why using `Bundle` and `NSBundle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It seems you somehow copied and pasted a computed property inside another computed property.
2. You are needlessly using `Bundle` and `NSBundle`. Just use `Bundle`.
3. Your `applicationVersionNumber` property should not be a `class` property. This lets you use the property on any bundle, not just the main bundle.
4. Your property should return an optional so the caller can decide how to deal with the version not being available.

Here's the fixed extension:

```swift
extension Bundle {
    var applicationVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }

    var applicationBuildNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }
}
```

And the updated caller:

```
let versionNumber = Bundle.main.applicationVersionNumber ?? "Version Number Not Available"
```

Comment: Thank you very much HangarRashHang. It work's now

Comment: I have one last question, how can I display a version number like that `15a240d` ? I have tried it but it doesn't work. So it would look like that
```swift
var applicationBuildNumber: String? {
   return infoDictionary?["CFBundleLongVersion"] as? String
}
```
But I don't know what the `15a240d` is called. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me again. Should I create a new question for that?

Comment: Isn't that `CFBundleVersion` (as shown in my answer)? If not, yes, post a new question with all relevant details.