# Display a version number like that '15a240d'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a question how can I display a version number like that `15a240d` ? I have tried it but it doesn't work. So it would look like that

```swift
var applicationBuildNumber: String? {
   return infoDictionary?["CFBundleLongVersion"] as? String
}
```

But I don't know what the `15a240d` is called. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me again.

Here's my full code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// An extension that gets the build and version number of this xcodeproj
/// as a String
///
extension Bundle {
    var applicationVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }
    
// create a var like above

    var applicationBuildNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }
}


struct SLInfoView: View {
    let versionNumber = Bundle.main.applicationVersionNumber ?? "Version Number Not Available"
    
    let buildNumber = Bundle.main.applicationBuildNumber ?? "Build Number Not Available"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section() {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Version number")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(versionNumber)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Version")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("15a240d") // FIXME: Replace Text with the version number thingy
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Build")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(buildNumber)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                    
                } header: {
                    Text("General infos")
                } footer: {
                    Text("Those informations are needed if you want to report an issue")
                }
            }
                .navigationTitle("Info")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SLInfoView()
}
```

> Note: This question is related to another question: [Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268944/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-a-type-annotation/77271019#77271019)

I need to display a version number in the format like `15a240d`. Despite searching online, I haven't found a solution.

### What have I tried?

I tried replacing the CFBundleVersion with something like CFLongBundleVersion, ProductVersionString or `kCFBundleVersionKey as String` but it didn't work

### What could solve this issue?

Link the git commit sha - [Add git commit SHA to iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388553/add-git-commit-sha-to-ios-application)
https://github.com/siggb/GitVersioningOnXCode

Comment: print `infoDictionary` of the Bundle, and you might see on which key is your info, no? It's hard to tell on which key you put it

Comment: From where did you get the idea that such a key exists at all in the dictionary?